# Visual Studio 2015 crashing on iOS Application tab

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am facing a problem since I've installed visual studio 2015 with xamarin, the project was running fine until yesterday evening when I decided to deploy iOS app. On opening .iOS properties > iOS Application, visual studio get crash unexpectedly and gets restart. Please help. 
Following is the screenshot

[Visual Studio 2015 crashing on iOS Application tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzWs8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. The issue was invalid Entitlements.plist tags

For some reason Entitlements.plist tags changed to following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

I created new project, opened its plist file and replaced my project Entitlements.plist with new one. The valid tags where following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <dict/> </plist>
```

Comment: Looks like you figured it out a few seconds before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the info.plist and entitlements.plist first (in an XML editor) and make sure that looks ok first.

Then save it and try to open the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by manually checking out the Entitlements.plist file for editing.